# Problems with WebClient.Upload and Socket.BeginReceive

Tags: c#, sockets, serialization, asynchronous, beginreceive

I'm currently writing a simple web server and some clients to use it. My customer wants to be able to extend the functionality of the upcoming solution to include web clients but we need to have minute control of the communication so a simple web server is the solution.

Anyway, there are two symptoms and I can reproduce them both to 100% by running a bunch of unit tests. The problem comes when I upload a simple string to the server, using a "POST" command. It's not really something I will do in reality but I can't move ahead not understanding what's going on. I have a unit test that simply serializes the string "Hello World!", using a BinaryFomatter. I prefix the resulting byte array data with an integer indicating the length of the streamed data. A very simple protocol for sure but it works just fine in all other situations (larg object graphs mainly). I have two scenarios:

1. Upload a very short string ("Hello World!")
2. Upload a large string (a few thousand characters).

When I run that unit test without first running any other unit tests this works as expected but whenever I run all my unit tests this one always fails in two different ways:

1. The short string doesn't seem to trigger the receiving socket to receiver it. More specifically, when I call Socket.BeginReceive() my callback is never called.
2. The long string does trigger reception as expected but the stream gets corrupted. The length prefix (4 byte, serialized Int32) contains a very large value. Certainly not the correct one.

This is the interesting part of the server code:

```
    public void Receive(bool async = false, TimeSpan timeout = default(TimeSpan))
    {
        var asyncResult = _socket.BeginReceive(_lengthBuffer, 0, _lengthBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, receiveLengthCallback, this);
        if (!async)
            Wait(timeout == default(TimeSpan) ? Timeout : timeout);
        if (IsComplete)
            return;

        SocketError socketError;
        _socket.EndReceive(asyncResult, out socketError);
        SocketError = socketError;
    }

    private static void receiveLengthCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    {
        try
        {
            var data = (SocketDataReceiver)asyncResult.AsyncState;
            var count = data._socket.EndReceive(asyncResult);
            if (count == 0)
            {
                // connection was closed, abort ...
                data.onReceiveAborted();
                return;
            }
            data._index += count;
            if (data._index < data._lengthBuffer.Length)
            {
                // length only partially received, get rest ...
                data._socket.BeginReceive(data._buffer, data._index, data._lengthBuffer.Length - data._index, SocketFlags.None, receiveLengthCallback, data);
                return;
            }

            // done receiving the length prefix ...
            data._length = BitConverter.ToInt32(data._lengthBuffer, 0);
            data.Data = new byte[data._length];  // ERROR (this will cause an OutOfMemoryException when data._length has become corrupted
            if (data._length == 0)
            {
                // not much to do here, cancel ...
                data.onReceiveAborted();
                return;
            }

            data._index = 0;
            if (data._buffer.Length > data._length)
                data._buffer = new byte[data._length];

            // start reading content ...
            data._socket.BeginReceive(data._buffer, data._index, data._buffer.Length - data._index, SocketFlags.None, receiveCallback, data);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // todo handle exception in Socket reception code
            throw;
        }
    }

    private static void receiveCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    {
        try
        {
            var data = (SocketDataReceiver)asyncResult.AsyncState;
            var count = data._socket.EndReceive(asyncResult);
            if (count == 0)
            {
                // connection was closed, abort ...
                data.onReceiveAborted();
                return;
            }
            foreach (var b in data._buffer)
            {
                data.Data[data._index++] = b;
                if (--count == 0)
                    break;
            }
            if (data._index == data._length)
            {
                // all data has been received ...
                data.onReceiveComplete();
                return;
            }

            // more data is on the way ...
            data._socket.BeginReceive(data._buffer, 0, data._buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, receiveCallback, data);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // todo handle exception in Socket reception code
            throw;
        }
    }
```

I might be drawinf the wrong conclusions here but I haven't seen any problems with streaming object graphs whereas doing the same with serialized strings is problematic. I can't understand why. I would appreciate any hints that could point me in the right direction.

**EDIT**

It appears that the problem is caused by a previous test case and it has nothing to do with sending a string, which was my first suspicion. Is there a way data can "linger" between two successive uploads? The client socket is recreated for every upload though.

This is the client side of the upload:

```
    private void upload(string documentName, object data, int timeout = -1)
    {
        // todo Handle errors
        WebClientEx client;
        using (client = new WebClientEx())
        {
            client.Timeout = timeout < 0 ? UploadTimeout : timeout;
            try
            {
                var response = client.UploadData(
                    new Uri(ServerUri + "/" + documentName),
                    StreamedData.Wrap(data));
                // todo Handle response
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Failed while uploading " + data + ".", ex);
            }
        }
        GC.Collect(); // <-- this was just experimenting with getting rid of the client socket, for good measure. It has no effect on this problem though
    }
```

Cheers

/Jonas

Answer (score 1):

If you catch too few bytes on the first read you are issuing another call to `BeginRead` only this time you are passing in the wrong buffer. I'm not 100% sure this is the cause of this particular issue, but it's not right:

```
        if (data._index < data._lengthBuffer.Length)
        {
            // length only partially received, get rest ...
            data._socket.BeginReceive(data._buffer, data._index, data._lengthBuffer.Length - data._index, SocketFlags.None, receiveLengthCallback, data);
            return;
        }
```

Comment: Yes, I did see that just after having posted. It's not the real issue here (I have never seen that code being executed) but thanks for pointing it out!